# 404 for route that exists according to rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I created a member route on a resource called `groups` in my Rails app.

```
  resources :groups do
    member { post :vote }
  end
```

If I do rake route, it shows that this route exists

```
   vote_group POST   /groups/:id/vote(.:format)        groups#vote
```

In Ember, I created a GroupController

```
App.GroupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    actions: {

    vote: function() {

    $.post("vote_group_path", {
      username: this.get("username"),
      id: this.get("id")
     ....
```

However, when I click submit on the form, I'm getting a no-route matches error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST]"/vote_group_path"):
```

I'm wondering if this is because I'm not specifying which group through the inclusion of an id. In the template that shows each group, I'm able to display the name and the id

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="group">

      {{ model.name }}
      {{ model.id }}
      {{ partial 'groups/form'}} 

</script>
```

but I'm not sure how to include the `id` for the group as a kind of hidden element in the form (if that's even necessary to make the route work)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="groups/_form">
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "vote" on="submit"}}>
   <div class="controls">
      {{input value=username type="text"}}
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">follow</button>
</form>
</script>
```

I know I'll eventually need the group id in the vote action of the groups controller, but I'm not sure if the lack of the id is making the route appear not to exist

```
 def vote
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `vote_group_path` is a helper method generated by Rails that can only be used inside of the Rails app.  Let's say that you have a group with an `id` of `1` assigned to the `some_group` variable.  Inside of the Rails app, if you call `vote_group_path(some_group)` it will return the string `'/groups/1/vote'`.  That helper function does not cross the application layer boundary into your JavaScript.  In JS you'll want to manually build the full path of `'/groups/1/vote'`.

Something like :

```
$.post("/groups/" + this.get('id') + "/vote", {...});
```